# UILabel text offset/indent

Tags: iphone, uilabel

How can I add an indent or offset to text inside a UILabel? It needs to be a specific pixel size, independent of the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create another `UILabel` and then set each label's frames to be a certain width apart, that way it could be done dynamically rather easily if thats what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: well, my original desire was for adjusting the indent in a textLabel of a generic tableViewCell, so I cannot manipulate the frame of that label directly. I wanted to do that because I was also adding another view to the contentView of the cell and it would overlap the label otherwise. Ended up using a trick where a UIView can be converted to UIImage. So I set my custom view as an image to cell.imageView.image, which takes care of indentation.